# Working hours in EU with multiple jobs

Tags: human-resources, united-kingdom, germany, working-conditions

I am working as an International research assistant (in a University Library) in Germany, a startup (based in London) ask me to work as a research consultant (kind of freelancer, 5-10 hours per week). I am working as full time at 40 hours and also doing a part-time PhD at 4 hours per week (not being paid). My employer gave official permission for the part-time PhD.

I wanted to work as a research consultant because we exchange data and technology. As per the EU, regulation, there is a limit of a maximum of 48 hours per week.

I have two questions-

1. Can I work as two jobs(full-time and freelancer) in Germany and UK?
2. How does employer check the exact number of the working hours across Germany and London?

Comment: The UK is not in the EU. While EU regulations continue to apply as of today, it is looking incredibly unlikely that situation will continue from 1st January.

Comment: @PhilipKendall Thanks, but even in the EU or just Germany, How does employer check the exact number of the working hour?

Comment: @AlexKujur why would employer be the one checking it? They may ask for you to declare the hours, so they can be sure that its complaint with whatever law, but they won't actually go and test whether you've lied to them, usually. Who may get interested in actual numbers is gov body responsible for enforcing those rules.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul I am not thinking to lie but I am wondering how it works, so government check it with the tax rate or labour department check it, right?

Comment: @AlexKujur In my experience no one cares until someone complains.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul Thanks

Comment: duderoo there's nothing stopping you *voluntarily* working more hours

Comment: This is in scope for Workplace.SE, because a HR manager in Germany should know restrictions on side jobs. (As always questions about European regulations very immediate close votes. That's very sad.)

Answer (score 3):

> Can I work as two jobs(full-time and freelancer) in Germany and UK?

Yes. The only thing stopping you are any contractual clauses, which I'm assuming don't apply, as you have your employer's permission. (Permission to pursue a PhD might not be the same as "yes you can get additional job" - check your contract).

> How does employer check the exact number of the working hour across
> Germany and London?

They won't. They might ask you to self certify your hours.

From memory, the working time directive is a rolling average (I think based on the average number of weekly hours across 17 weeks). It states that you cannot be *made to* exceed the maximum number of hours. You can choose (freely) to opt out, in which case you may exceed the limits. This opt out form is for your employer's benefit and ensures they won't get sued for your excessive hours.

For clarity "made to" would include an employer suggesting you'll be terminated unless you agree.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you talking about the uk or german laws and regs?

Comment: You cannot opt out of the German *Arbeitszeitgesetz* (Law on Working Hours). It explicitly says that working hours for different employers have to be combined. However, a freelancer is not an employee and (IANAL!) therefore not covered by this law.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul, I was talking specifically about the (EU mandated) legislation implemented by the UK, the _Working Time Directive_. I don't know anything about how other EU nations have implemented this (see Roland's comment). Based upon what OP states, I don't believe there's anything in UK law to prevent him/her. As usual OP, seek professional advice starting with the German equivalent of _Citizens Advice Bureau_ (if you have such).

Answer (score 2):

In your case the **German laws are leading**, because you're living in Germany permanently. Therefore Germany working time rules apply, no matter where the employers are located.

Your main question seems to be **about the working hours**. As you noted there is a limit of 48 hours per week. Your contracts must be very clear that there is not intention to work more than that.

In addition to that

- You are not allowed to work more than 8 hours per day permanently, so that you have to work on Saturdays or Sundays
- Over 6 calendar months or 24 weeks the average working hours per day must not exceed 8 hours

Again, these are the common regulations independent of the employer's location.

Of course your **employers cannot observe** how much you are working for other companies, so they have to ask you. If they get notice that you are violating the working hour limit, they have to take action, which could result in terminating your contract. Violating the rules would be especially risky, because all contracts which are exceeding the limit would be void and **employers wouldn't need to pay you - even for work already done**.

I assume that your part time PhD doesn't count towards the limit, but this might be worth checking with a lawyer.

**TLDR**

Make sure that your contract with the UK based startup doesn't included minimum working hours above 8 hours. In case you are fully flexible, be very strict about the time limit at least for the first months to create a track record, so that you might temporarily go above it when needed.

*Further reading: [Höchstarbeitsgrenze bei zwei Arbeitsverhältnissen](https://www.bund-verlag.de/aktuelles%7EHoechstarbeitsgrenze-bei-zwei-Arbeitsverhaeltnissen%7E#)*

Comment: OP wants to combine work as a regular employee with work as a freelancer (*Freier Mitarbeiter*). Your answer doesn't cover this.